# PHP session sending header "Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate". How to change to "Cache-Control: s-maxage=10, public, max-age=10"

Tags: php, session, caching, session-variables

PHP session is causing each page to contain the header `cache-control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate`.

I need to override this behavior and change it to `Cache-Control: s-maxage=10, public, max-age=10` or even just `cache-control: public, max-age=10`.

I've tried to use session variables `session_cache_limiter('public');` and `session_cache_expire(1);` but, the expire value is in minutes and I cant work out how to set it to 10 seconds.

How can I set `session_cache_expire(1);` to 10 seconds?
If that's not possible, how else can I override the session header and set the cache control to 10 seconds?

Comment: Not sure what the point of such an extremely short caching interval is supposed to be, but I guess you could simply use `header` after `session_start`, to overwrite the system-generated header with your own.

Comment: @CBroe, the short cache time is for dynamic content.  Having no cache works well, but I would like to increase the time to 10 seconds to match the caching time of some of my functions (which use redis).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of @Amikot40 and @CBroe, I've solved the issue.

```php
// remove pragma no-cache header with session variable
// this also sets the Cache-Control header, but you will change that after session start
session_cache_limiter('public');

session_start();

// cache for 10 seconds
header("Cache-Control: s-maxage=10, public, max-age=10");

// expire in 10 seconds
$expire_time = new DateTime('UTC');
$expire_time->add(new DateInterval('PT10S')); // add 10 seconds
$expire_time = $expire_time->format(DateTimeInterface::RFC7231);
header("Expires: $expire_time");
```

Answer (score 0):

In PHP you use header() function:

```
<?php
  header("Cache-control: public, max-age=10");
  header("Expires: Sat, 1 Apr 2022 05:00:00 GMT");
?>
```

Alternate option is to use HTML tags on top - before first <?php opening:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="max-age=10" />
    <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="Sat, 1 Apr 2022 05:00:00 GMT" />
</head>
<?php

// your php code starts here.
```

If you using any frontend framework which has its templates - you should look for meta tags there, or possibly in that framework documentation (possibly there are dedicated functions for that).

Answer (score 0):

```php
// remove pragma no-cache header with session variable
// this also sets the Cache-Control header, but you will change that after session start
session_cache_limiter('public');

session_start();
// cache for 10 seconds
header("Cache-Control: s-maxage=10, public, max-age=10");

// expire in 10 seconds
$expire_time = new DateTime('UTC');

$expire_time->add(new DateInterval('PT10S')); // add 10 seconds
$expire_time = $expire_time->format(DateTimeInterface::RFC7231);
header("Expires: $expire_time");
```